# Using JSZIP to make zip folder of .package files

Tags: javascript, jquery, zip, blender, jszip

**I am using `JSZIP` to make a zip file for a bunch of .package files (for the Sims 4 game).**

I am confused on the `zip.file(url, contents)` part, because according to some forums, where they zip image files, they first convert into `Blob`-objects, but am I suppose to do the same for .package files?

Also I am unsure what the MIME type is for .package files when I do the metadata typing, I couldn't find it under the list of Media Types in the docs.

This is just a simple repo with js, html, css.

I tried doing `this.responseText` as the contents parameter for `zip.file(url, contents)`, but it corrupted my .package files.